# how to configure codeigniter hmvc in subdomain

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain, hmvc

H,
I'm using codeigniter hmvc framework.i don't know how to configure this fo subdomain. i've installed it but not working. any help please.

```
project/
     application/
               controller/installer
     modules/
```

default controller is pointed to  installer.php

```
$route[default_controller] = 'installer';
```

but unable access the controller.

Answer (score 1):

No matter it is hosted in subdomain or main domain. You need to do couple of things to make it workable.

**Step one**
Config `base_url` in config.php as follows:

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

**Step two** Check your `.htaccess`. It should looks like as bellows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: `.htaccess` vary depending on server. In some server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ariful. but i had already tried these things. its working without any configuration on localserver. but not working in subdomain on live server.

Comment: just try to access your subdomain in maindomain.com/subdomain format and let me know what happen...

Comment: Just let me know one more thing. Is `installer` a directory or a file?

Comment: installer is a file. its default controller.

Answer (score 0):

find this file

application/config/config.php

edit here thats all

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://subdomain.example.com/";
```

Comment: it displays blank page. but it works fine on localserver.

Comment: add these lines at he top of index.php file  `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);`  @KenStewart

Comment: still displays blank page

Comment: in index.php file also check here (at top) it must be development to be able to see errors.  `define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');` @KenStewart